# Setting up a .pro file for a WxWidgets project in QtCreator in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, wxwidgets, ubuntu-18.04

I installed WxWidgets-3.2 from source on **Ubuntu 18.04** following these instructions:

```
$ cd buildgtk
$ ../configure --with-gtk
$make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Everything was installed successfully.
Also I have a **QtCreator 4.5.2**, **Qt 5.9.5**,**GCC compiler 7.3**, **qmake**.
Here is `wx-config` result:

```
wx-config --cxxflags
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

```
wx-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu-3.2
```

Now I want to create my first WxWidgets project in QtCreator in Ubuntu 18.04.
To do this, I need to correctly configure a .pro file.
Let me know what the **.pro** project file should look like so I can run a simple WxWidgets example

Comment: there is nothing special. Create new project, add appropriate include folders, library search path and libraries itself with `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs`, compile and run. Let us know if there problems.

Comment: I have read about this, but I don't have enough experience in Linux to customize QtCreator to use installed WxWidgets.

Comment: are you familiar with QtCreator? Do you know where to go to change the project parameters?

Comment: @Igor, yes, sure. Now my QtCreator can compile simple projects. But I need an example .pro file to get started with WxWidgets.

Comment: what is `pro` file? Also make sure you don't just blindly add -I, -L and -l options. Since you are on Linux - open the Terminal and run `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs`. Check what parameters are `define`ed to compile the application and then .ink it and then update the options in your IDE.